# unable to load image in android using picasso library

Tags: android, url, imageview, picasso, image-loading

hope you are doing good,I am working on an app,In that i want to load an image from url into an imageView,I have used Picasso lib for this,But it gives me uncaught exception,I have checked and debugged for is proper url is coming or not and its perfect,Still i am facing this issue,Can anybody help me to solve this?my code is as below:
**code**

```
Picasso.with(NewProfileActivity.this)
                        .load(mUser.userAvatarPath)
                        .into(iv_profile);
```

here,"iv_profile" is imageView,mUser.userAvatar Path is image url.

Comment: @TimCastelijns - Its uncaughtException.

Comment: That doesn't mean a lot. Include the stacktrace

Comment: check whether url is correct or not.

Comment: @SathishKumarJ - this is my url.http://stush.net/Stoosh/api/Uploads/Pictures/171/user-avatar-171-90680605ab666156e8385ba2908dcd0e.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
Picasso.with(this).load("http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg").placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).into(imageViewCenter);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Picasso.with(this).load("http://city/1.jpg").placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_city)).into(imageViewCity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your image URL, if it is not containing http:// prefix then the images will not be loaded. Make sure the image URL is prefixed with http://

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageView);
```

**placeholder** helps when your original url is not loaded.

and put

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your manifest.xml

This may helps you.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code its work in your case

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(Imagename.png).fit().centerCrop().error(R.mipmap.ic_profile).fit().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_profile).fit().into(imgNDProfile);
```

Comment: may be error in your code in somewhere else find it out, may be your image name have capital letters or other issue check our code Man..